# Capitalization when sentence begins with chemical name

Tags: grammar, capitalization

It is generally considered poor form to begin a sentence with a numeric digit. For example,

> 4% of people are old.

should be

> Four percent of people are old.

What is the rule when you need to begin a sentence with a chemical name that should not be converted to a word?

> 2-chloroprocaine is an anesthetic.

It doesn't seem right to capitalize the first letter after the number, because chemicals are not normally capitalized.

> 2-Chloroprocaine is an anesthetic.

Spelling it out seems inaccurate.

> Two-chloroprocaine is an anesthetic.

Rewriting the sentence makes it confusing.

> An anesthetic, 2-chloroprocaine, is.

Comment: This matter is one that would be ruled by the house style guide of the journal or publisher.  My advice would be to go to such a journal and see how they do it. Here's an example where it begins the sentence: https://books.google.com/books?id=t7A0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=chloroprocaine+has&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ8rio-cXVAhXLOyYKHUejAhAQ6AEIkAEwEQ#v=onepage&q=chloroprocaine%20has&f=false

Comment: As a frequent contributor to chemistry.se and ell, @M.A.R might have some insight...

Comment: I am not aware of any rule about not starting sentences with a number. In your example, a general rule is to write out numbers less that ten, rather than use the numeral.

Comment: Tempted to +1 this question based only upon your choice of J. R. "Bob" Dobbs as avatar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An article called [*Effects of Concentration and Volume of 2-Chloroprocaine on Epidural Anesthesia in Volunteers*](http://anesthesiology.pubs.asahq.org/article.aspx?articleid=2027212) has a sentence beginning with the chemical, which is capitalized:

> 2-**C**hloroprocaine has different physicochemical properties (higher pKa and lower lipid solubility) than other commonly used local anesthetics.

Otherwise, it remains lowercase:

> This study was performed to delineate effects of a threefold difference in concentration and volume of 2-**c**hloroprocaine on sensory and motor block during epidural anesthesia in a crossover fashion.

Comment: This is completely correct.